# Two variables are not matching on PHP

Tags: php

So I have a string that for some reason, is returning as: `12Ã—12`. I did this in my code: `utf8_decode($variant['size'])` and received `12×12`.

But this still isn't matching my string of `12x12`

So I have `12×12` that is not showing as equal in php with: `12x12`.

The X does look a little different but how do I fix this issue?

Comment: where is that `$variant['size']` coming from and why isn't it already utf-8?

Comment: It's coming from an API but I don't know why....

Comment: if you have no control of the source then you might have to run some processing on the string before comparing. That might include str_replace() of known values. Sounds sucky

Comment: See `preg_replace`, `str_replace` or better even [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) for substituting Unicode glyphs into ASCII equivalents.

Comment: I've tried `str_replace` but it still didn't work.

Comment: In `12×12` the `×` is the multiplication symbol, which obviously doesn't equate to `x`. (Note the `×` doesn't reach the baseline in the text.)

Comment: Why do you expect strings with different characters to be equal? `x` and `×` look kind of similar, but they're not the same. One is a letter, the other is a mathematical symbol.

Comment: I don't "expect" anything. I'm asking how to make them the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `12×12` the `×` is the multiplication symbol, which obviously doesn't equate to `x`. *Note that × doesn't reach the baseline in the text.*

You should test for this multiplication symbol instead, if you can.